# update .htaccess file to include redirect for macbook air

Tags: mod-rewrite

I have redirect coding in .htaccess file - I just want to include macbook air in the list of devices to forward to a mobile specific site...

is this the right code to target it?

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "macbook air"[NC,OR]

thanks,

Comment: I believe serverfault.com would be the better site for this type of question, by the way.

Answer (score 2):

There's no way to determine the (Apple) laptop model type from a HTTP user agent string, or any other HTTP header, regardless of what browser they are using.

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure that browsers on a MacBook Air don't send a different user agent, so it's not possible to redirect its users to a mobile version.

That said, the MacBook Air functions more like a regular laptop (with keyboard and largish screen, not like the iPad), so most users would probably prefer the regular version anyway.